# `gem install therubyracer` fails on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: ruby, rubygems, v8

I would appreciate some help in getting `gem install therubyracer` to work. Here is the error:

```
$ gem install therubyracer
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lobjc... yes
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
    --with-objclib
    --without-objclib
extconf.rb:15:in `<main>': undefined method `include_path' for Libv8:Module (NoMethodError)
```

Here are some notable steps that I ran before the error. They worked fine:

```
$ gem install libv8
$ brew install v8
```

My environment is:

- Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4
- ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0] (via rvm)
- V8 version 3.9.24 (via homebrew)

Comment: Note: I hoped that http://wellconsidered.be/post/18996655760/therubyracer-compile-error-osx-10-7-lion would be of use, but it did not help.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$ gem uninstall libv8
$ gem install therubyracer
```

(A big thanks to http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4306127)

Comment: I'm on ruby 1.9.3p194 and this didn't work.  "make: g++-4.2: No such file or directory"

Comment: I tried installing every combination of the gems but nothing worked.  I ended up just copying the gemdir from the ruby1.9.2p125 directory over to the new p194 directory.

Comment: @jspooner This is relatively tricky install process for many people. If you feel up to it, post a question like I did, with your configuration settings in detail, what you tried, and so on.

Comment: :( didn't work for me, this is what i get:
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/lionel_lei/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lobjc... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling rr.cpp
make: clang++: No such file or directory
make: *** [rr.o] Error 1

Comment: @lionel Can you post a Gist of exactly what you've tried? Have you tried setting up a new `rbenv` or `rvm` install from scratch and writing down the steps (in a Gist) to isolate the problem? Did you do `brew install v8` first?

Comment: Hi David, I posted this as a new question so I could accept answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720909/therubyracer-install-error-i-tried-all-other-so-solutions-and-still-no-luck

I have not tried rbenv or brew install v8. I haven't used those before. But I could look into it. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I set a version for therubyracer as '0.11.4' and it helped. The default therubyracer version resolved happens to be '0.9.x' which has issues with available versions of 'libv8's.

Comment: for Rails the second step here should be just running "bundle install" after uninstalling libv8. Also make sure to do "gem "therubyracer", :require => 'v8'" in your gemfile

Answer (score 43):

```
gem uninstall libv8
brew install v8
gem install therubyracer
```

Comment: Thanks Ken. Took about 3-5 minutes to install. Everything working with therubyracer-0.11.2 which auto-installed libv8-3.11.8.13.

Answer (score 40):

But, *why* is this happening, you ask? And why does uninstalling `libv8` and reinstalling `therubyracer` fix the problem?

The answer is at the bottom of the error message (from orig post). Ignore the stuff about

```
probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers
```

This is an incorrect assumption by whoever wrote that error message. At the bottom, you see what Ruby has to say about it:

```
undefined method `include_path' for Libv8:Module
```

In my case, I was trying to install `therubyracer-0.9.8` with `bundle install`, and for some reason, it was trying to use my copy of `libv8-3.11.8.13`, which had been installed at some point, probably as a dependency of some other gem.

I don't know why it was trying to use the newer version, because `therubyracer.gemspec` contains `s.add_dependency "libv8", "~> 3.3.10"`. And my `Gemfile.lock` says to use `libv8 (3.3.10.2)`. But alas, that is indeed what was happening.

And it's true that `Libv8:Module` does *not* have the method `include_path` in `libv8-3.11.8.13`, but it *does* in `libv8-3.3.10.2`

So that is why uninstalling *all* of your versions of `libv8` and then re-installing `therubyracer` works. Because all the versions of `libv8` that *do not have* the method `include_path` are removed completely, and the `libv8` that *does have* the method `include` path is reinstalled when you reinstall of `therubyracer`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write the explanation for why this works

Comment: What if I don't want to delete the newer version of libv8, in case of other projects depending on it? What do I do then?

Comment: Found it! Checked that my `Gemfile` didn't need a specific therubyracer version. Then I deleted the old `Gemfile.lock` which specified an old therubyracer version, which in turn required the old `libv8` version. (Someone must have committed it to the project previously, and then bundle install tried to use it when installing.) When I ran `bundle install` again, it made a new `Gemfile.lock` with new connections, and hooked the latest `therubyracer` version up to the latest `libv8` version, no problem.

Answer (score 15):

Considering none if the above worked for me 100%, I thought I'd post what did (as part of a rails project):

```
gem uninstall libv8
bundle update therubyracer
```

This made sure I got the latest `therubyracer`, and also a more recent version of `libV8`, and seem to fix the multiple issues I was hitting, from missing libv8.a files, to undefined methods.

Comment: it was the only one that helped me on osx 10.9.1 (Maverick)

Comment: can you please explain why I have to run this command everytime I need to deploy one particular application. I am using a Mac.

Comment: Shouldn't need to run it more than once? unless you have several versions of either gem, and you are doing something weird with the Gemfile.lock?

Comment: This did it for me, Rails 4, Mac OS 10.9.4. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 12):

At last I use therubyracer 0.11.0beta5 as a solution.

Using therubyracer (0.11.0beta5)

add following on Gemfile

```
gem 'therubyracer', '~> 0.11.0beta5'
group :libv8 do
  gem 'libv8', "~> 3.11.8"
end
```

then `bundle install`

Mac OSX 10.8 Moutain Lion

Comment: I tried this, but:
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/lionel_lei/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
checking for main() in -lobjc... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling accessor.cc
make: clang++: No such file or directory
make: *** [accessor.o] Error 1

i am on Rails 3.2.6, ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.4.1], osx 10.7.4

Answer (score 10):

If you need `0.11.3` and it's failing give this a shot for Mac OS X 10.9...

```
gem uninstall libv8
brew install v8
gem install libv8 -- --with-system-v8
gem install therubyracer -v '0.11.3' -- --with-system-v8
```

See [this issue](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/issues/215) for more details.

You probably don't need the `-- --with-system-v8` on the last line but I did it just to be safe since I saw it start doing `Fetching: libv8-3.11.8.17-x86_64-darwin-13.gem (1%)` when I ran the command...

Anyhow, it worked for me when all the other things did not.

Comment: This also worked for me, the --with-system-v8 was mandatory on the last line

Answer (score 7):

For anyone encountering this issue on Mac OSX 10.8 Mountain Lion when attempting to upgrade their **Gemfile** with `gem 'therubyracer', '0.11.0'`, just upgrading the system `libv8` gem worked for me (no uninstallation of any other gem necessary):

```
$ gem update libv8
$ bundle install
```

#### Edit

If you use [Travis-CI](https://travis-ci.org/) (or other CI tools located on other servers, I assume), you will need to explicitly add the `libv8` gem to your **Gemfile** as well:

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'libv8', '3.11.8.3'
```

then `bundle install` as usual.  Just note that `libv8` can take a significant amount of time to install and I've noticed that it may end up being the cause of going over [Travis CI's timeout limits](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/build-configuration/#Build-Timeouts), causing your build to fail.  You can mitigate this slightly be not including development environment gems in your builds:

**.travis.yml**

```
# ...
bundler_args: --binstubs=./bundler_stubs --without development
```

#### Update

Yep, pretty much all my Travis builds timeout and fail because of this.  If anyone knows a way to solve this problem (I would hope "downgrade `therubyracer`" is a last resort), please leave a comment!

#### Update 2

This may not work for all apps, but it seems that my Rails 3.2.9 apps didn't actually need `therubyracer` or `libv8` after all.  After removing those gems from my **Gemfile**, I confirmed that my specs passed, pushed again to Travis and it built successfully.  So, I guess getting rid of those gems (if you're not sure you actually need them) is at least worth a try.

#### Update 3

Thanks to [Paul Annesley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/430695/paul-annesley) for confirming that if you're on Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion, you don't need  `therubyracer` gem at all since the OS already comes bundled with Apple JavaScriptCore, its own Javascript runner.  At the time of the original answer, I was on Snow Leopard and hence needed it.

Comment: Regarding "Update 2" and not needing `therubyracer` or `libv8`, presumably that means you're either not using CoffeeScript, or using an alternative JS runner.

Comment: I do use Coffeescript, for sure.  Looking back on it, I believe I made that edit soon after I upgraded OS X from Snow Leopard to Mountain Lion, so perhaps Mountain Lion has its own JS runner that made `therubyracer` unnecessary...?

Comment: Ah yes; “Apple JavaScriptCore - Included with Mac OS X” is listed as one of the runtimes on https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thanks very much for confirming that.  I've added it to the answer.

Comment: for some reason, I have to run this command EVERY time I start running one application locally. Can someone explain, why I have to run it every time as opposed to one time.

Answer (score 4):

For me, removing the Gemfile.lock file and running `bundle install` worked it's magic.

Comment: Note that running `bundle update` is effectively the same thing as deleting `Gemfile.lock` then running `bundle install`.

Answer (score 3):

OSX 10.8.2, ruby 1.9.3p125

None of the above worked for me... I got tired of trying to find the right gem for my environment, so I just soft linked to the g++ target this things was missing:

```
sudo ln -s `which g++` /usr/bin/g++-4.2
```

Not as helpfully for remote deployments, but get the job done on my workstation.

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar issue, but it was also complaining about not finding g++-4.2.  I *did* have XCode command line tools installed, but it was looking for /usr/bin/g++-4.2, I had g++ (which was a symbolic link pointing to llvm-g++-4.2).  Anyway, I just created a symbolic link to g++ and tried the bundle install again... it worked!

`$  cd /usr/bin`

`$  sudo ln -s g++ g++-4.2`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error, this worked for me:

1. From console: `gem uninstall libv8`
2. In your Gemfile, add the following:

   ```
   gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby, :require => 'v8'
   gem 'libv8', '~> 3.11.8'  # Update version number as needed
   ```
3. From console: `bundle install`

If you were in the middle of upgrading therubyracer gem, you may want to run `bundle update therubyracer` after that as well. (Consider specifying a version number)

This was on Mac 10.6 (Snow Leopard).