# therubyracer install error

Tags: rubygems, therubyracer

As you can see below, libv8 installs fine, but therubyracer doesn't. I'm using Mac 10.7.4.

```
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1> gem install libv8
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed libv8-3.11.8.3
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for libv8-3.11.8.3...
Installing RDoc documentation for libv8-3.11.8.3...

~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1> gem install therubyracer
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/rdp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lobjc... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/rdp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby
    --with-objclib
    --without-objclib
/Users/rdp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/rdp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:461:in `try_link0'
    from /Users/rdp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:476:in `try_link'
    from /Users/rdp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:619:in `try_func'
    from /Users/rdp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:845:in `block in have_library'
    from /Users/rdp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/rdp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/rdp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/rdp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/rdp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/rdp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
    from /Users/rdp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
    from /Users/rdp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:840:in `have_library'
    from extconf.rb:10:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/rdp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/therubyracer-0.10.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/rdp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/therubyracer-0.10.1/ext/v8/gem_make.out
```

Here's the `mkmf.log`, which is located in `~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/therubyracer-0.10.1/ext/v8>`.

File Edit Options Buffers Tools Help

```
"/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -o conftest -I/Users/rdp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.3.0 -I/Users/rdp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1/rub\
y/backward -I/Users/rdp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/Users/rdp/.rvm/usr/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE    -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-\
parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-functio\
n-declaration  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/rdp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib -L/Users/rdp/.rvm/usr/lib -L.      -lruby.1.9.1  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: int main() {return 0;}
/* end */
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can use the Libv8 from the brew instead of the one from gem. You can do that by following commands:

```
$ gem uninstall libv8
$ brew install v8
$ gem install therubyracer
```

Comment: If you need to install a specific version of therubyracer, specify it here. `gem install therubyracer -v '0.11.4` (with your version number here) instead of `gem install therubyracer`

Comment: Worked for me as well.

Answer (score 13):

@Haegin's answer in https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8/issues/205

```
brew uninstall v8
brew install v8-315
gem uninstall -a libv8
gem uninstall -a therubyracer
gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.17' -- --with-system-v8
gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.2' -- --with-v8-dir=$(brew --prefix v8-315)
```

Comment: I looked for several ways to solve this problem and this was the only one that worked for my macOS Monterey. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

For an older project I had to used the 0.10.1 version of rubyracer on mavericks (bootstrap depends on it)

So I had to use an older version of gcc

1. edit your .zshrc or .bashrc

   ```
   export CC=/usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/gcc-4.2
   export CXX=/usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/g++-4.2
   export CPP=/usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/cpp-4.2
   ```
2. be sure that you have uninstalled all older versions of libv8

   ```
   gem uninstall libv8
   ```
3. install your version of therubyracer

   ```
   gem install therubyracer -v=0.10.1
   ```

Answer (score 5):

For Linux:

The code below is of course correct

`$ gem uninstall libv8`

`$ gem install therubyracer`

But sometimes it does't help because you haven't program `make`. **AT FIRST** you need install `make`. To do this, run:

`sudo apt-get install build-essential`

And only after that:

`gem install therubyracer`

Comment: Thanks!! this is the answre that solve all my problems

Answer (score 4):

On Mavericks, you just need to update to therubyracer 0.12.0

Answer (score 3):

These steps worked for me:

- `brew uninstall v8`
- `brew install v8-315`
- `gem uninstall -a libv8`
- `gem uninstall -a therubyracer`
- `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.19' -- --with-system-v8`
- `gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.3' -- --with-v8-dir=$(brew --prefix v8-315)`

Comment: thanks, this worked:
MacOS BigSur, rbenv, ruby 2.5

Answer (score 2):

Mac 10.10.5, Ruby 2.1.0 this worked for me:

```
gem uninstall libv8
gem uninstall therubyracer

brew upgrade gcc
brew install v8

bundle config --local build.libv8 --with-cxx=/usr/local/bin/gcc-6
gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.17' -- --with-system-v8
gem install therubyracer -- --with-v8-dir=/usr/local/opt/v8-315

bundle install # worked !
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me was putting these steps together on 10.7.4

```
export CC=gcc-4.2

sudo ln /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2

gem uninstall libv8
gem install therubyracer
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the exact same issue just till now.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905820/gem-install-therubyracer-fails-on-mac-os-x-lion) saved me.

to sum up, you need to do this:

```
$ gem uninstall libv8
$ gem install therubyracer
```

before i fixed this issue, i had v8 installed in my mac. i don't know if this helped, since it seems have sth to do with js interpreter, I thought it might help.

Answer (score 0):

On Mountain Lion 10.8, it doesn't come preinstalled with a C compiler. You'll need to download and install the 'command line tools' package from Apple themselves, and then run `which gcc` to confirm it is installed. Everything should run fine from there on in.

Comment: Im also on mountain lion, and even with comand line tools I'm getting this error. I am able to individually install the gems, but not via a bundle. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

On OS X 10.7 I actually found that the "Command Line Tools" package wasn't enough, I had to install the full-blown XCode package, then gem install worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem when I upgraded from OSX Mountain Lion to OSX Mavericks.

Upgrading from ruby-1.8.7-p354 to ruby-1.8.7-375 did the trick for me.  If you are on ruby-1.93-p125, you may want to try upgrading to 1.9.3-rc1  (which is above p484 already)

libv8 (3.16.14.3-x86_64-darwin-13) and the therubyracer (0.12.0) gems installed without problem.

assuming you use rbenv:

```
rbenv install 1.9.3-rc1
rbenv rehash
rbenv shell 1.9.3-rc1
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/issues/420#issuecomment-253592865

```
gem uninstall therubyracer
gem uninstall libv8
brew uninstall v8
brew install v8
gem install libv8
gem install therubyracer
```

It helped me. Parameters: `ruby 2.3.3`, `rails 4.2.9`

Answer (score 0):

Install v8:

```
brew install v8@3.15
```

After install gem `libv8`:

```
gem install libv8 -v 3.16.14.19 -- --with-system-v8
```

And install specific version of `therubyracer`:

```
gem install therubyracer  -v '0.12.3' -- --with-v8-dir=/usr/local/opt/v8@3.15
```