# error installing therubyracer error failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am giving this command to command prompt "buncle install"..and it gives an error "install therubyracer".  When i install therubyracer i got this error "error installing therubyracer error failed to build gem native extension".   Anyone who knows please help me.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126465/bundle-install-update-libv8-therubyracer-installation-fails-with-native-ex

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Libv8 from the brew instead of the one from gem. You can do that by following commands:

```
$ gem uninstall libv8


$ gem install therubyracer
```

Comment: Might also need to `brew install v8` | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598655/therubyracer-install-error