# I want to run an old rails 3.3.2 project, seeking particular and specific steps for that

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, legacy-code

I want to run this project, https://github.com/ebidadmin/ebid33 I tried `rails s` and `bundle install` but was instead faced upon a series of different bundler version compatability and dependency issues. It's been a week or so that I'm trying to run. I just feel like I've reached a dead end.

My Ruby Version is 2.6.3, I also have 1.8.7 Installed.
My rails version is 6.0.3.2

when I run bundle install this is what I get :

```
Fetching gem metadata from http://gemcutter.org/.
Retrying dependency api due to error (2/4): Bundler::MarshalError TypeError: incompatible marshal file format (can't be read)
        format version 4.8 required; 60.33 given
Retrying dependency api due to error (3/4): Bundler::MarshalError TypeError: incompatible marshal file format (can't be read)
        format version 4.8 required; 60.33 given
Retrying dependency api due to error (4/4): Bundler::MarshalError TypeError: incompatible marshal file format (can't be read)
        format version 4.8 required; 60.33 given


Retrying fetcher due to error (2/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from http://gemcutter.org/
Retrying fetcher due to error (3/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from http://gemcutter.org/
Retrying fetcher due to error (4/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from http://gemcutter.org/
```

the Gemfile is like this

```
require 'rbconfig'
HOST_OS = RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os']
source 'http://rubygems.org'
source "http://gemcutter.org"
gem 'rails', '4.2.2'
gem 'mysql2'

group :assets do
    gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
    gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails", "2.0.3"
    gem "client_side_validations"
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.8.0.rc1", :group => [:development, :test]

group :test do
    gem "factory_girl_rails", ">= 1.4.0"
    gem "cucumber-rails", ">= 1.2.0"
    gem "capybara", ">= 1.1.2"
    gem "database_cleaner", ">= 0.7.0"
    gem "launchy", ">= 2.0.5"
    gem "mocha"
end

group :development do
    # case HOST_OS
    #   when /darwin/i
    #     gem 'rb-fsevent'
    #     gem 'growl'
    #   when /linux/i
    #     gem 'libnotify'
    #     gem 'rb-inotify'
    #   when /mswin|windows/i
    #     gem 'rb-fchange'
    #     gem 'win32console'
    #     gem 'rb-notifu'
    # end
    gem "guard", ">= 0.6.2"
    gem "guard-bundler", ">= 0.1.3"
    gem "guard-rails", ">= 0.0.3"
    gem "guard-livereload", ">= 0.3.0"
    gem "guard-rspec", ">= 0.4.3"
    gem "guard-cucumber", ">= 0.6.1"
    gem "rails-footnotes", ">= 3.7"
    gem "nifty-generators"
    gem "letter_opener"
    gem "capistrano"
end

gem "devise", ">= 1.5.0"
gem "has_scope"
gem "simple_form"
gem "nested_form", :git => 'git://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git'
gem "cancan", :git => "git://github.com/ryanb/cancan.git", :branch => "2.0"
gem "paperclip", '2.4.5'
gem "delayed_job_active_record"
gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.0"
gem "squeel"
gem "tire"
# gem 'elastic_searchable'
# gem 'rd_searchlogic', :require => 'searchlogic', :git => 'git://github.com/railsdog/searchlogic.git'
gem "ransack"#, :git => "git://github.com/ernie/ransack.git"
gem "ancestry"
gem "private_pub"
gem "thin"
gem "delayed_paperclip"
gem 'exception_notification'
gem 'therubyracer', :group => :production
gem "business_time"
```

The Gemfile.lock contents are like this :

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/ryanb/cancan.git
  revision: c94de4ab1805d2e080ebd658051c59d0ec5147ce
  branch: 2.0
  specs:
    cancan (2.0.0.alpha)

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git
  revision: 486e0f0e93f3ca455d5d0fc7869053257b6afce2
  specs:
    nested_form (0.2.0)

GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  remote: http://gemcutter.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.2)
      actionpack (= 3.2.2)
      mail (~> 2.4.0)
    actionpack (3.2.2)
      activemodel (= 3.2.2)
      activesupport (= 3.2.2)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.1)
      rack (~> 1.4.0)
      rack-cache (~> 1.1)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.1.2)
    activemodel (3.2.2)
      activesupport (= 3.2.2)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.2)
      activemodel (= 3.2.2)
      activesupport (= 3.2.2)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.2)
      activemodel (= 3.2.2)
      activesupport (= 3.2.2)
    activesupport (3.2.2)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    addressable (2.2.7)
    ancestry (1.2.5)
      activerecord (>= 2.2.2)
    arel (3.0.2)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
    builder (3.0.0)
    business_time (0.4.0)
      activesupport (>= 2.0.0)
    capistrano (2.11.2)
      highline
      net-scp (>= 1.0.0)
      net-sftp (>= 2.0.0)
      net-ssh (>= 2.0.14)
      net-ssh-gateway (>= 1.1.0)
    capybara (1.1.2)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      selenium-webdriver (~> 2.0)
      xpath (~> 0.1.4)
    childprocess (0.3.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0.6)
    client_side_validations (3.1.4)
    cocaine (0.2.1)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.2.0)
    commonjs (0.2.4)
    cookiejar (0.3.0)
    cucumber (1.1.9)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.2)
      gherkin (~> 2.9.0)
      json (>= 1.4.6)
      term-ansicolor (>= 1.0.6)
    cucumber-rails (1.3.0)
      capybara (>= 1.1.2)
      cucumber (>= 1.1.8)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.0)
    daemons (1.1.8)
    database_cleaner (0.7.1)
    delayed_job (3.0.1)
      activesupport (~> 3.0)
    delayed_job_active_record (0.3.2)
      activerecord (> 2.1.0)
      delayed_job (~> 3.0.0)
    delayed_paperclip (2.4.5.1)
      paperclip (>= 2.4.5)
    devise (2.0.4)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.0.3)
      railties (~> 3.1)
      warden (~> 1.1.1)
    diff-lcs (1.1.3)
    em-http-request (0.3.0)
      addressable (>= 2.0.0)
      escape_utils
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.9)
    em-websocket (0.3.6)
      addressable (>= 2.1.1)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.9)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    escape_utils (0.2.4)
    eventmachine (0.12.10)
    exception_notification (2.5.2)
      actionmailer (>= 3.0.4)
    execjs (1.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    factory_girl (2.6.4)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.9)
    factory_girl_rails (1.7.0)
      factory_girl (~> 2.6.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faye (0.8.1)
      cookiejar (>= 0.3.0)
      em-http-request (>= 0.3.0)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.0)
      faye-websocket (>= 0.4.0)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      yajl-ruby (>= 1.0.0)
    faye-websocket (0.4.4)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.0)
    ffi (1.0.11)
    gherkin (2.9.1)
      json (>= 1.4.6)
    guard (1.0.1)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    guard-bundler (0.1.3)
      bundler (>= 1.0.0)
      guard (>= 0.2.2)
    guard-cucumber (0.7.5)
      cucumber (>= 0.10)
      guard (>= 0.8.3)
    guard-livereload (0.4.2)
      em-websocket (>= 0.2.0)
      guard (>= 0.10.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    guard-rails (0.1.0)
      guard (>= 0.2.2)
    guard-rspec (0.6.0)
      guard (>= 0.10.0)
    has_scope (0.5.1)
    highline (1.6.11)
    hike (1.2.1)
    i18n (0.6.0)
    journey (1.0.3)
    jquery-rails (2.0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.0, < 5.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    json (1.6.5)
    launchy (2.0.5)
      addressable (~> 2.2.6)
    less (2.0.11)
      commonjs (~> 0.2.0)
      therubyracer (~> 0.9.9)
    less-rails (2.1.8)
      actionpack (>= 3.1)
      less (~> 2.0.7)
    letter_opener (0.0.2)
      launchy
    libv8 (3.3.10.4)
    mail (2.4.4)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    metaclass (0.0.1)
    mime-types (1.17.2)
    mocha (0.10.5)
      metaclass (~> 0.0.1)
    multi_json (1.1.0)
    mysql2 (0.3.11)
    net-scp (1.0.4)
      net-ssh (>= 1.99.1)
    net-sftp (2.0.5)
      net-ssh (>= 2.0.9)
    net-ssh (2.3.0)
    net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0)
      net-ssh (>= 1.99.1)
    nifty-generators (0.4.6)
    nokogiri (1.5.2)
    orm_adapter (0.0.6)
    paperclip (2.4.5)
      activerecord (>= 2.3.0)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.2)
      cocaine (>= 0.0.2)
      mime-types
    polyamorous (0.5.0)
      activerecord (~> 3.0)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    private_pub (1.0.1)
      faye
    rack (1.4.1)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.2)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.2)
      actionpack (= 3.2.2)
      activerecord (= 3.2.2)
      activeresource (= 3.2.2)
      activesupport (= 3.2.2)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.2)
    rails-footnotes (3.7.5)
      rails (>= 3.0.0)
    railties (3.2.2)
      actionpack (= 3.2.2)
      activesupport (= 3.2.2)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    rake (0.9.2.2)
    ransack (0.6.0)
      actionpack (~> 3.0)
      activerecord (~> 3.0)
      polyamorous (~> 0.5.0)
    rdoc (3.12)
      json (~> 1.4)
    rest-client (1.6.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    rspec (2.9.0.rc2)
      rspec-core (= 2.9.0.rc2)
      rspec-expectations (= 2.9.0.rc2)
      rspec-mocks (= 2.9.0.rc2)
    rspec-core (2.9.0.rc2)
    rspec-expectations (2.9.0.rc2)
      diff-lcs (~> 1.1.3)
    rspec-mocks (2.9.0.rc2)
    rspec-rails (2.9.0.rc2)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec (= 2.9.0.rc2)
    rubyzip (0.9.6.1)
    sass (3.1.15)
    sass-rails (3.2.4)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    selenium-webdriver (2.20.0)
      childprocess (>= 0.2.5)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rubyzip
    simple_form (2.0.1)
      actionpack (~> 3.0)
      activemodel (~> 3.0)
    sprockets (2.1.2)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    squeel (0.9.5)
      activerecord (~> 3.0)
      activesupport (~> 3.0)
      polyamorous (~> 0.5.0)
    term-ansicolor (1.0.7)
    therubyracer (0.9.10)
      libv8 (~> 3.3.10)
    thin (1.3.1)
      daemons (>= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.6)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    thor (0.14.6)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    tire (0.3.12)
      activemodel (~> 3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rake
      rest-client (~> 1.6.0)
    treetop (1.4.10)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.0.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.1)
      less-rails (~> 2.1.6)
      railties (>= 3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.32)
    uglifier (1.2.3)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.0.2)
    warden (1.1.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    will_paginate (3.0.3)
    xpath (0.1.4)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)
    yajl-ruby (1.1.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  ancestry
  business_time
  cancan!
  capistrano
  capybara (>= 1.1.2)
  client_side_validations
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  cucumber-rails (>= 1.2.0)
  database_cleaner (>= 0.7.0)
  delayed_job_active_record
  delayed_paperclip
  devise (>= 1.5.0)
  exception_notification
  factory_girl_rails (>= 1.4.0)
  guard (>= 0.6.2)
  guard-bundler (>= 0.1.3)
  guard-cucumber (>= 0.6.1)
  guard-livereload (>= 0.3.0)
  guard-rails (>= 0.0.3)
  guard-rspec (>= 0.4.3)
  has_scope
  jquery-rails
  launchy (>= 2.0.5)
  letter_opener
  mocha
  mysql2
  nested_form!
  nifty-generators
  paperclip (= 2.4.5)
  private_pub
  rails (= 3.2.2)
  rails-footnotes (>= 3.7)
  ransack
  rspec-rails (>= 2.8.0.rc1)
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
  simple_form
  squeel
  therubyracer
  thin
  tire
  twitter-bootstrap-rails (= 2.0.3)
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
  will_paginate (~> 3.0)
```

I just want the project to run. any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: _a series of different bundler version compatability and dependency issues_ That's not helpful information. What if I try to run the project and get totally different issues? Of course I'd have no way of knowing because you haven't said what your issues actually are. Please take a moment to read all the articles in the Help Center about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) then come back and update this question to reflect those guidelines. Otherwise, it's very likely this question will be closed for lack of specificity leaving you without an answer.

Comment: @anothermh I apologize for the insufficient information regarding my question. I edited my question.

Comment: You have to use the exact same Ruby and Rails versions that were used in the past. If you want to use Rails 6 instead you have to adapt your code (rewrite) accordingly. Otherwise just use the same old versions of each and incrementally update Rails versions from 3.2.2 to 6, going through Rails 4, Rails 5.. and updating Ruby version when necessary  (It may be cumbersome)

Comment: when I ran ```rvm gemset create rails-3.2.3
rvm use 1.8.7@rails-3.3.2 --default
gem install rails ``` the versions being the versions the project was built on . I got this error everytime I ran ```rails -v``` or ``` rails s``` ```Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from /usr/local/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
        1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:308:in `activate_bin_path'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:289:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem railties (>= 0.a) with executable rails (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

Comment: Why is your gemfile different from the Repo here : https://github.com/ebidadmin/ebid33 One is 3.2.2 and the other 4.2.2. Also for the error I am not too sure. It seems to be using Ruby 2.5 (as seen in some error paths) but this version is too young for such an old project. Have you switched to Ruby 1.8 (in RVM) before installing your app from the repo ?

Comment: I must have changed it in my desperate quest of trying to run it. I will revert it back to 3.2.2 on the local repo

Comment: It may work but it is better to not modify the Repo. So that the Rails version and gems verions perfectly match.

Comment: Your question is all over the place -- Which version of ruby/rails/etc are you actually trying to use?! I'd suggest reverting everything, and trying to run the original project with the original versions of all libraries. There is no guarantee that changing random dependencies will work without significant other updates to the project; whereas running the original library versions *should* work.

Comment: Your question mentions rails `3.3.2`, `4.2.2` and `6.0.3.2`. Stick to `3.2.2` and don't try any upgrade yet! Your question also mentions ruby `1.8.7`, `2.5.0` and `2.6.3`... Again, stick to `1.8.7` and let's go from there!

Comment: Also, why are you running `gem install rails`? Don't try to install gems manually; run `bundle install`.

Comment: @TomLord You are right, I took a deep breath and re-cloned the repo and started with installing the correspondent ruby & rails versions. and ran ```bundle install``` it went on installing the gems till I got an error about therubyracer gem. it just didn't succeed in installing even after I ran ```gem install therubyracer -v '0.9.10'```

Comment: OK, and what is *that* error? There are a few [common problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11598655/1954610) installing older libraries like this, as you may have an incompatible newer version of `gcc` or whatnot on your machine. The solution is generally to resolve the gem installation issue, rather than trying to upgrade the library (and cause a chain-reaction of other dependency problems).

Comment: @TomLord ```Fetching therubyracer 0.9.10```
```Downloading therubyracer-0.9.10 revealed dependencies not in the API or
the lockfile (libv8 (~> 3.3.10)).
Either installing with `--full-index` or running `bundle update
therubyracer` should fix the problem.

In Gemfile:
  twitter-bootstrap-rails was resolved to 2.0.3, which depends on
    less-rails was resolved to 2.1.8, which depends on
      less was resolved to 2.0.11, which depends on
        therubyracer```

Comment: Did you try [the top answer to the post I linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14080341/1954610)?

Comment: Yes I tried the following but no use, ```gem uninstall libv8``` and then ```gem install therubyracer -v '0.9.10'``` now when I run the latter. I get ```Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
/home/maryan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p330/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:46: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
``` ... and alot of lines of errors starting with g++ @TomLord

Comment: Why does that error say you're using ruby `1.9`? I thought we were sticking to `1.8`. Hopefully the error message says to read the log file, and hopefully the log file contains something more useful - which you can google and see what other people did to resolve.

Comment: No, I went with 1.9 when I re-cloned the repo. it said in the project readme that either is fine for running.

Comment: ```/home/maryan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p330/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
g++ -I. -I/home/maryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p330/gems/libv8-3.3.10.4-x86_64-linux/lib/libv8/v8/include -I/home/maryan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p330/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/home/maryan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p330/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/home/maryan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p330/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.   -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long  -fPIC -o v8_except```

Comment: @TomLord alot of the remaining errors are very much similar to this one. any clue?

Comment: That's only the command, not the error? Unless you tried to post the full error, and StackOverflow comments are too long to submit it? Anyway... once again my top suggestion would be to read through those other answer above, as it seems many other people encountered problems with newer `gcc` versions, or by not running installing `--with-system-v8`, or by not setting `--with-v8-dir`, ... I can virtually guarantee there were thousands of people seeing this exact same error before you, so it's hopefully just a matter of finding an existing solution on stackoverflow

Comment: @TomLord Okay, Thank you! I'll let you know

Comment: @TomLord I was able to overcome the bug by once again taking a deep breath and looking at it from a different perspective. turns out running the ruby-1.9.2 can not install therubyracer gem whatsoever, therefor, I used rvm to use ruby-1.9.3 to install therubyracer and it worked. I re-```bundle install``` my whole project using the ruby-1.9.3 and voila. bundle is completed!

Comment: upon bundle complete I turn to run ```rake db:create``` but it gives me the following error ```rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- bundler/setup

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
``` any thoughts? @TomLord

Comment: Try an explicit `bundle exec rake db:create`? Or try running with `--trace`, like the error says, for more detail

Comment: @TomLord I tried ```bundle exec rake db:create``` and was struck with this ```/home/maryan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
        from /home/maryan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
``` note that my ruby version is '1.9.3'  any clue?